# ajax image onload popup

Tags: ajax, popup

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadXMLDoc()
{

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }

else

  {// code for IE6, IE5

  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

    {

    window.alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }

  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","popup.html",true);

xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:loadXMLDoc()">

<div id="myDiv"><h2>AJAX image popup</h2></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually i want to use it on a joomla page, but i couldn't get any extension to do that so i created this script but the popup display html instead of the image in the page code.
I also tried to get the image directly, but its couldn't display it.

All i want to achieve is for an image to popup when page loads.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard browser "popup" achieved from the JavaScript `alert()` function can't display images.  It's plain text only.

One way you could display a "popup" which contains rendered HTML would be to use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  This essentially creates a modal `div` on the page which mimics the functionality of a "popup" within the confines of the DOM.  That `div` can contain any HTML you want:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <!-- put your markup here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it work, but you will need to include the jquery library and ui library.

Comment: @JosiahChinedu: Well, if you don't want to use the libraries then you could always do it manually.  It's just a styled `div`.